# How to set the Text in TextFields to the numbers of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, textfield

I need to set each TextField in my JFrame to the corresponding number in a pre-generated array of numbers but I do not know how.

This is what I need it to look like:

[image]

Here is the ActionListener Class that I am working with:

```
public class RandListener implements ActionListener
{
private final JTextField[] tF;

public RandListener(JTextField[] tF)
{
    this.tF = tF;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    int [] rArray = new int[10];
    Random rNum = new Random();
    for(int k = 0; k < rArray.length; k++)
    {
        rArray[k] = rNum.nextInt(100);             
    }

    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("bRand"))
    {

        for(int k = 0; k < tF.length; k++)
        {
            tF[k].setText(/*I need to set the text of my TextFields to the numbers in the array*/);
        }
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("bMaxMin"))
    {
        //I need to find the maximum and minimum of the Array here
    }
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on how Strings in Java work. Basically, if you would want to turn the number into a string:

```
    tF[k].setText(/*I need to set the text of my TextFields to the numbers in the array*/);
```

turns into:

```
    tF[k].setText("" + rArray[k]);
```

I believe this is done automatically by Java; number boxing turns the primitive type into its respective wrapper (int -> Integer) and then then toString() is called on the Integer object which represents the primitive type.

Now, to find the minimum and maximum, you're going to have to think a little bit. This is an elementary problem companies will give to weed out bad candidates. Figure it out once on your own and you'll never forget it. Think of how you would do it as a human; you take the current biggest/smallest and compare it to whatever you're looking at currently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it helped a lot. I will definitely do some deeper thinking on finding the maximum/minimum.